# How to concatenate the echo of an array as expressed through a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, concatenation

I'm trying to create a variable that prints strings that are concatenated with results that are pulled from an array with a foreach loop, but every time I add on the actual array, I get a server error.

Here's my code:

```
$emailmsg .= "Price: " . $totalprice . " // Order: " . 
foreach ($productarray as $book1=>$info1)
             {if ($book1 > 0)
             {echo $info1 . ", Quantity: " . $book1 . " // ";}
                    };
```

I've tried removing each semicolon as well as the echo statement to see if that was part of it but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What server error are you getting?

Comment: It just says "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request," which is the same error I see anytime I have a syntax error.

Comment: You have a dot (.) at the end of the first line

Comment: Well, indent your code properly, and learn the PHP syntax. You are way off. Use `php -l file.php` on the command line to get a sense of what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dot at the end of the first line, I think the proper thing you want to do is:

```
$emailmsg = "Price: " . $totalprice . " // Order: ";
foreach ($productarray as $book1=>$info1)
{
    if ($book1 > 0)
    {
        echo $emailmsg .= $info1 . ", Quantity: " . $book1 . " // ";
    }
}
```

EDIT:
To have the message printed once with the order details:

```
$emailmsg = "Price: " . $totalprice . " // Order: ";
$order = '';
foreach ($productarray as $book1=>$info1)
{
    if ($book1 > 0)
    {
        $order .= $info1 . ", Quantity: " . $book1 . " // ";
    }
}
echo $emailmsg.$order;
```

Comment: The dot is there because I'm trying to concatenate the results of the foreach loop onto the $emailmsg.

Comment: But I want the array to be a part of the email message,not the other way around? I don't want the email message to be reprinted each time a result from the array is called.

Comment: Basically I need to echo $emailmsg with the results from the array elsewhere, so the array itself needs to be concatenated within $emailmsg.

Comment: Ah, okay, perfect. That's what I needed. I don't know why that solution didn't cross my mind before. In any case, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit - I believe the 500 error is because of the stray dot . 
just before the foreach loop

Not sure I'm following the input / desired output, but does something like this help?

```
foreach ($productarray as $book1=>$info1)
             {if ($book1 > 0)
             {$emailmsg .= "Price: " . $totalprice . " // Order: " .  $info1 . ", Quantity: " . $book1 . " // ";}
                    };
```

If not, what does $productarray look like?  and what does your desired output look like?

Comment: The dot is there because I'm trying to concatenate the foreach loop onto "Price: " . $totalprice . " // Order: ".  I want the echoed array to be a part of the $emailmsg, not the other way around?